# Proper, code compliant, way to move an electrical outlet

Tags: electrical

I Need to move this outlet to the other stud.

My first thought was to splice new wire inside the box and move it over, BUT NEC doesn’t allow splicing in-wall if the box is not reachable/accessible.

Also, I’m not sure if NEC allows Romexs to be run between studs ( *only stapled to the side* )

How do I do this while remaining code complaint?

[image]

Comment: I have many thoughts, what is your **specific question**.

Comment: @AlaskaMan Specific question is, how do I move this outlet to the stud on the right while being code compliant.

Comment: Every point along the wall (wrapping around walls but not crossing thresholds) must be within 6' of a socket.  If you move this socket, will you open a gap wider than 6' to a threshold or 12' to the next socket?

Comment: @Harper Haha. There is not a single outlet in this house that meets the 6 foot requirement. But yeah, I’m only moving it 16”.

Comment: @JeffGeorge Well your house may be grandfathered, but part of grandfathering is **you can't make it *worse***.   I'm not sure how you'd get caught at that, but if you did, it would stink.   Now if you're moving it to open up a threshold, thresholds interrupt the 6' requirement since they don't want people bridging thresholds with extension cords.

Comment: Do you access all the way to other end of that length of wire? Ideally you replace the whole thing.

If not, if you move it to the other stud, do you have enough slack to move it and keep it at the right height and have enough wire coming out of the box?

Comment: Is there a reason the old box can't stay put?

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Are you saying, split/pigtail in the current box, run new wire from it, and then just put a face plate cover on it?

Comment: @Drew Not enough slack. That wire goes up to feed second floor outlets as well.

Comment: What I may do is splice/pigtail in the current box, then put a solid face plate on it, then run FMC horizontally to the next stud. I’ll just have to research to ensure that NEC allows running FMC in between studs.

Comment: @JeffGeorge -- yeah, a short length of really any wiring method suitable for concealed applications can cross a stud bay as you propose, plain old NM is fine for this job (especially since you have a plastic box, which makes using metal conduit of any sort rather difficult)

Comment: Is the box feeding another wire coming from below? Or does it only have the wire coming out the top?

Comment: @Jack Both above and below. It’s coming from the basement and feeding the upstairs. I think I’m simply going to splice within the box, and run a horizontal line to the next stud. Pigtail the wires coming from basement, upstairs, and new side run, all together.

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel Thank you for that info. I think that’s what I’ll do. Pigtail a new line into the box and create a superset horizontal line across the stud bay.

Comment: If the hole drilled in the bottom plate and the top plate were in the center of the stud bay, all the staples could be pulled and set to the other side. You would need to remove more drywall to determine that.

Comment: Here is what I ended up doing (photo below). Ran a new 10/2 line into the box. Pigtailed all together (basement, upstairs, and new run). Put a blank face plate on it. New 10/2 cable was ran to new spot for outlet. 

![Click here for the photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BnWTa.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

You can use a special In wall splice called a tyco or nm splice and add enough to move the receptacle over. These splices are not required to be accessible and are kind of expensive at 15-20$ but they do what you want and are available at big box and specialty stores.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I ended up doing (photo below). Ran a new 10/2 line into the box. Pigtailed all together (basement, upstairs, and new run). Put a blank face plate on it. New 10/2 cable was ran to new spot for outlet.

[image]

Comment: As long as you didn't overstuff a box, this works I reckon....